# Iptables Postrouting with SNAT for a paritcular destination IP

Tags: iptables

I want to define a rule in iptables for postrouting in ubuntu as below:

```
$IPTABLES -t nat -A POSTROUTING  -o $EXTIF -p tcp -d xxx.xx.xx.8 -j SNAT --to-source xxx.xx.xx.238
```

It means for destination with IP xxx.xx.xx.8 (a oublic IP) , I want its source IP to be xxx.xx.xx.238.

The above rule is not working . 
Any suggestions.
Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

I got the solution myself as below:
I added a new IP in sub interface(eth0:0), with my required  NATting IP. For example xxx.xx.xx.238 with eth0:0.
Now I added a new rule in IPTABLE as

```
$IPTABLES  -t nat -A POSTROUTING  -o eth0.0 -p tcp -d xxx.xx.xx.8 -j SNAT --to-source xxx.xx.xx.238
```

.

When accessing the application in IP xxx.xx.xx.8, It shows the NATting IP to be xxx.xx.xx.238.

Comment: The "-d" parameter helped me,
and did you intend to write "eth0.0"? Because you write that your sub-interface is "eth0:0"

Comment: Yes, for sub interface we need to write as eth0.0 in iptables rule. I have used IP xxx.xx.xx.238 for eth0:0 sub interface.